# where does outlook store what attachments are safe to open?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, attachments

Outlook evidently has a setting somewhere that controls whether an email attachment of a given file type can be directly opened, or whether the user must go through the "You should only open attachments from a trustworthy source" dialog.  One of the options in this dialog is "Always ask before opening this type of file".

To un-check the "always ask" setting, you have to close outlook, re-open as an administrator, then attempt to open every file type that you want to change this setting for, then unset the "always ask"... then close outlook and re-open as a normal user.  I'm trying to find a way to automate this process, but I can't seem to figure out where this setting is stored.  I would assume it's buried somewhere in the registry, but then again outlook also has a habit of storing plenty of stuff (***cough*** autocomplete list ***cough***) in random database files.

Does anyone know where/how outlook stores the "safety state" of attachment file types?

Comment: How about, Outlook -> File -> Options-> Privacy centre... (can't remember the exact name) but its where all security settings are.

Comment: I think you mean "Trust Center" - which doesn't appear to have this setting. And I'm really looking for something programmatic.  Everytime someone pushes an update it wipes out all my settings (this may be a corporate policy thing) but I want something I can script or dump into a .reg file so that I can return all these attachment settings to "open without asking" in one fell swipe.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bout of unfathomable irony, Adam Fowler posted this blog entry the day after I asked the question:  https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2017/09/disabling-outlook-opening-mail-attachment-prompt/.

To summarize (in case his post vanishes one day):

in the registry there's a class for each "trusted" file type under this branch: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes`

For example, Excel files might be `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\Excel.Sheet.8`

or (for a newer version of excel...) `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\Excel.Sheet.12`

Setting/adding an `EditFlags` key with a hex value of `00,00,01,00` will remove the "Always ask before..." popup and allow the files to just open.

So if you want to allow the opening of Visio files, version 15, you need to add/edit a registry entry that looks like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\Visio.Drawing.15]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,01,00
```

The real insight from Adam's post was that you can use [Procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (from sysinternals) to decode what file types you're interested in.  To do this, open up procmon and set up filters for something like `Process name contains outlook.exe` and `Operation is SetRegValue`.  This will show you events where a registry value is set by outlook, and more importantly which value it is.  The mapping of file types to "class names" is the tricky part - it's not always at all obvious how this works, I think each application can grab some of these (in my case IrfanView is a image viewer that's associated with .gif and .jpg extensions)

Next, open up Outlook as an Administrator, and open an example of each file type that you want to NOT be nagged about.  As you go through these, uncheck the "always ask..." option in the open dialog, and as you open the files the corresponding registry entries will be edited.  Procmon will show you the exact entries that are changed, save these into a .reg file for later and you can just re-set them all at once.

In my case there are enough that get routinely reset that I banged out a little python script to generate the .reg file... just add/remove any leafs that you need to the list and you should be good to go.

```
header_row = 'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00'
reg_branch = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes'
leafs = [
    'Excel.Sheet.12',
    'Word.Document.12',
    'PowerPoint.Show.12',
    'Excel.Sheet.8',
    'Word.Document.8',
    'PowerPoint.Show.8',
    'Visio.Drawing.15',
    'IrfanView.png',
    'IrfanView.gif',
    'IrfanView.jpg',
    ]
key_name = '"EditFlags"'
key_value = 'hex:00,00,01,00'


print(f"{header_row}\n\n")
for leaf in leafs:
    print(f"[{reg_branch}\{leaf}]")
    print(f"{key_name}={key_value}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking this prompt happens in Outlook after the: "Enable Protected View for Outlook Attachments" under Trust Center (from Excel or Word) is unchecked. Keep in mind that Outlook Trust Center doesn't show this option to disable/enable protected view settings, you will have to go to the Office Suite program in question. If you enable this setting you won't get the prompt back, however the protected view settings alert when you open Excel/Word will now appear. I end-up doing a fix provided on MS forum by Roady: Right Click on Outlook shortcut and running it as an Administrator and then did a Ctrl + Shift while opening the attachment, this will allow you to uncheck the box for "Always ask before opening this type of file".

> Blockquote https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/how-to-disable-the-warning-on-opening-any/b424facc-3855-4467-8225-cb0c9de44c11

Comment: Yep - that part I can make work, but it requires me to manually open one of each attachment type that I want to trust.  I'm specifically asking about a way to do this programmatically, either via a PowerShell script or a set of registry entries or similar...